# Can you pass an XSLT select value to a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Can an XSLT variable value be passed to a JavaScript variable. If so how it can be done? I have the following xml file:

```
<b:blog-items>
    <b:blog-item author="A124" dateTime="11/10/2013 14:00">
        <b:title>This is a text title</b:title>
        <b:text>
            <b:paragraph>This is a paragraph</b:paragraph>
        </b:text>
    </b:blog-item>
</b:blog-items>
<a:authors>
    <a:author id="A124">
        <a:name>John</a:name>
        <a:surname>Doe</a:surname>
        <a:dob>13/12/1980</a:dob>
    </a:author>
</a:authors>
```

With XSLT I am transforming it into an HTML and I am accessing all the values. Now I need to use JavaScript in order to link the author id from blog-items to authors. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arbitrary data as non-HTML elements/attributes along with the generated DOM. Possibilities:

- If HTML is not strict, just add arbitrary non-HTML element to HTML/HEAD.
- If HTML is strict (checked against XML schema), you'll have to add xmlns attribute to the root element and non-HTML element should belong to that xmlns. You still pass it in HTML/HEAD.
- if you are allowed to use HTML5, you can use [HTML5 custom data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)